# "I shoulda 'STOOD' IN BED?"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I've heard folks use "stood" as a kind of past-participle of the verb "stay" - as in: "I shoulda stood in bed". I had always thought it was some kind of uneducated regionalism...

But, it's New Years, (Happy and Healthy, y'all) and I'm watching the 'Twilight Zone' marathon on TV, and Rod Serling just used it...

Rod Serling!

So, my question is...

Is there a reference here? Was it an expression coined at one time (like,"A little dab'll do ya") in advertising or another medium? Or, is it a literary reference..? Does anyone know?

Comment: Did you even google "stood in bed"? The link in Josh's answer is the first result for me.

Comment: Nope. It didn't even occur to me. I only use Google for shopping and "Who the hell is that actor?"

Comment: Well it seems there's no shortage of people prepared to google and paste the result into an answer box.

Comment: My mother, although a farm girl from Southern Illinois, was well read, would occasionally use that expression, but knowing full well that it was not proper! I think it was kind of a little "funny" that she got a kick out of!

Comment: The Twilight Zone episode  was [Cavender Is Coming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavender_Is_Coming).  The two main characters are played by Jesse White and Carol Burnett, and "*stood in bed*" is exactly the kind of expression *they* would use.  That's why Rod Serling deliberately used it in the introduction.  He similarly ends the closing narration with "*And this message from the Twilight Zone: Lotsa luck!*".

Answer (score 8):

Probably from here:

[I should have stood in bed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/should-have-stood-in-bed--i)

> - I've had such a bad day that I should never have gotten up at all. For example, And then I got rear-ended at the stop sign—I should have stood in bed.
> - This ungrammatical colloquial phrase—properly put as stayed in bed —is ascribed to fight manager Joe Jacobs, who in 1935 saw his first baseball game, the opening game of the World Series between the Detroit Tigers and Chicago Cubs. It was a very cold day, and when asked what he thought of baseball, Jacobs replied, “I should have stood in bed.”

(The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary)

Comment: Here is an LA Times article that talks about it too.  http://articles.latimes.com/1989-11-09/news/vw-1199_1_joe-jacobs

Answer (score 0):

While I do not doubt that the use is perceived as ungrammatical, and that contemporary uses may be intended colloquially, the sense is quite possibly figurative and grammatical:

> b. fig. To remain steadfast, firm, secure, or the like. Also with adj. or adv.
>   ....
>   1605   Bacon Of Aduancem. *Learning* i. sig. D4,   If they **stand in seditions** and violent alterations.
>   1657   N. Billingsley *Brachy-martyrologia* xi. 35   Though some thus fell away, others stood fast, Remaining glorious Martyrs to the last.

["stand, v.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188960?rskey=yoDxak&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed January 02, 2016).]

The sense of your example, with this grammatical and figurative use, is

> I should have stayed secure in bed.

Answer (score 0):

Check Bartlett's Book of Quotations...it wasn't a baseball game it was a boxing match. And the man who quoted it was a boxer's manager. He was also quoted for; "We was robbed". Check it out...

Comment: The LA Times article by Jack Smith mentioned above says that the true source is moot.